# WebStorm and IntelliJ IDEA don't see custom NPM scripts in NPM run/debug configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, webstorm

I cannot see custom NPM scripts in either WebStorm 2016.3.2 or IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2's NPM run/debug configuration. I have selected the proper package.json file.

This is the script section from my package.json file and the run/debug configuration on the screen below. I cannot choose other custom commands, such as `clean:dist` (there is only `clean`), `e2e`, `pretest`, `test:passive`, etc. How I can choose these?

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "npm cache clean && rimraf coverage src/main/resources/static/*",
  "clean:dist": "rimraf typings src/main/resources/static/*",
  "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
  "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
  "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
  "clean:start": "npm start",
  "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
  "e2e": "protractor",
  "e2e:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
  "lint": "tslint './src/main/frontend/**/*.ts' --force",
  "pretest": "rimraf coverage && npm run lint",
  "test:passive": "ng test -w false",
  "test": "ng test",
  "pretest:phantom": "rimraf coverage && npm run lint",
  "test:phantom": "ng test -w false --browsers PhantomJS",
  "build": "npm run build:dev",
  "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
  "build:dev": "ng build -dev",
  "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
  "build:prod": "ng build -prod",
  "server": "npm run server:dev",
  "server:dev": "ng serve --p 4200 -pc proxy.json -dev",
  "server:prod": "ng serve --p 4200 -pc proxy.json -prod",
  "start": "npm run server:dev",
  "ncu": "ncu -a",
  "ng:upgrade": "ng init -n sqap-ui -sd src/main/frontend --style scss --prefix sqap --routing",
}
```

[image: Run configuration]

Comment: Are you using WebStorm or are you using IntelliJ?

Comment: I am using WebStrorm, but in Intellij it's the same.

Comment: Yes, it's the same sort of setup, but it's not the worst idea to narrow your scope between the two IDEs.  I know that IDEA is the kitchen sink, but if you're only using a part of it, it's good to specify that.

Comment: I have tested both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you like to run your custom scripts, select `run` as command, and then use the dropdown in `scripts` field to select your script. `test` command just runs `npm test`. Hint: you can create run configurations by right-clicking the script in **NPM** tool window that can be opened using `Show npm scripts` in package.json right-click menu